# How to validate 8 to 10 digit long phone number?

Tags: java, android, regex, validation

In my android application, phone number field used. 8 to 10 digit input value given by the user. How to validate  8 to 10 digit phone number using PHONE_REGEX?

I have already tried this method,

```
private static final String PHONE_REGEX = "\\d{8-10}";

  public static boolean isPhoneNumber(EditText editText, boolean required) {
    return isValid(editText, PHONE_REGEX, PHONE_MSG, required);
}
```

Comment: Use `"\\d{8,10}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
private static final String PHONE_REGEX = "\\d{8,10}";

public static boolean isPhoneNumber(EditText editText, boolean required) {
return isValid(editText, PHONE_REGEX, PHONE_MSG, required);
}
```

instead of

```
private static final String PHONE_REGEX = "\\d{8-10}";

public static boolean isPhoneNumber(EditText editText, boolean required) {
return isValid(editText, PHONE_REGEX, PHONE_MSG, required);
}
```

only one small mistake.Before ask a question,refer previous stack answers.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try `\\d{8,10}` instead of `\\d{8-10}`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this for validation.

```
    public static boolean isValidIndianMobile(String mobile) {

            if (mobile == null || mobile.trim().length() <= 0) {
                return false;
            }
            mobile = removeAllSpace(mobile);

            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[7-9][0-9]{9}");
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(mobile);
            return matcher.matches();
        }


   public static String removeAllSpace(String s) {
           if (s == null) return "";
           return s.replaceAll("\\s", "");
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `\\d{8,10}` instead of `\\d{8-10}`

and trim() the text

```
private static final String PHONE_REGEX = "\\d{8,10}";

  public static boolean isPhoneNumber(EditText editText, boolean required) {
    return isValid(editText.getText().toString().trim(), PHONE_REGEX, PHONE_MSG, required);
}
```

Comment: Use `\\d{8,10}` instead of `\\d{8-10}`